# Rewrite rule doesn't work all lowercase

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to fix this weird problem since 3 hours. I cannot believe it.

I have "RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]" in htaccess
I've just found out that, if I type like this; www.sitename.com/Profile/1, www.sitename.com/proFile/1, www.sitename.com/profilE/1 it works but if I type all lower case, it doesn't work. It doesn't make sense to me. What would be causing the problem?

This is all .htaccess file;

```
# 0 ---- Turn Rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

# 1 ---- Rewrite for profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 

# 2 ---- Establish a custom 404 file not found page
ErrorDocument 404 /views/404.php

# 3 ---- Redirect 403 forbidden to custom made 404 page
ErrorDocument 403 /views/404.php

# 4 ---- Prevent directory file listing in all of your folders
Options -Indexes

# 5 ---- Make pages render without their extension
Options +MultiViews
```

**SOLUTION**

If you want to remove .php or .html extensions and rewrite the profile.php as profile (with the same name), you must use this way to remove file extensions. Do not use Options +Multiviews

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: try to rename your profile.php to some other name to debug it

Comment: zairwolf, yes I ve just found out that, that's is the problem. I cannot give the same name! I watched many videos and everybody gives same name. I don't understand, why mine doesn't work.

Comment: Options +MultiViews is causing problem also. if I remove that, I can use same name. Piffff There must be a way around it. I need to both of them. I don't wanna name my files weirdly just to use both.

Answer (score 1):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html :

The effect of `MultiViews` is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.